# custom motion model for smac & mppi

Tags: path-planning, ros-humble, nav2

I'm employing the Smac Hybrid-A* Planner along with the Model Predictive Path Integral Controller for point-to-point navigation of a forklift, both indoors and outdoors. Notably, this forklift features a differential drive mechanism with two front wheels and an independently rotating rear wheel, mirroring a tricycle's kinematics. Additionally, I've opted for the "reeds shepp" method, addressing scenarios where in-place rotations aren't feasible.

Can I develop a custom motion model compatible with both the smac-planner and mppi-controller?

Any advice or guidelines on navigating these challenges would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simply a differential drive robot; you may simply use the differential drive motion model. The asymmetry is of no real concern to MPPI/Smac, just make sure you provide the appropriate footprint.

I don't know if there's some additional subtlety or problems you're hinting at needing that this doesn't provide, but that seems like the obvious solution :-)

Comment: Thanks for the rapid feedback.I was primarily considering confined spaces, such as inside a container. But now that I think of it, perhaps the Smac planner addresses this.

Comment: Great! Can you mark this as the answer to remove from unanswered questions queue?